# PHP SOAP Web Service send XML as parameter

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I have to send a XML file as parameter for a web service using SOAP. Any help with how can I do it?

And.. What's the XML Schema (XSD file)?

Answer (score 0):

The XML has to be passed as a string which will be encoded in order to be encapsulated in the XML SOAP Request.

In any case, I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator such as the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project which eases the request construction and the response handling,